# CDK Assume Role from optional Lambda role property/no non-null assertions within Composite Principal

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I have a role that is defined with a composite principal, but I can't add my Lambda function because of no non-null assertions, e.g. this fails:

```
assumedBy: new CompositePrincipal(
                ...
                new ArnPrincipal(this.cleLambdaFunction.role?.roleArn!)
            ),
```

How can I add my lambda function's role to `assumbedBy`/`CompositePrincipal`?
Is it possible for me to have my Lambda functions role assume my target role after definition of the target role? I'm wondering if there's a method that works like this

```
onboardingLambdaCle.lambdaFunc.lambdaFunction.role?.assumeRole(targetRole.roleArn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take advantage of TypeScript [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) and just check the existence of the property like this:

```
import { CompositePrincipal, ArnPrincipal } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import { Function } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';

declare const func: Function;

if (func.role) {
    const assumedBy = new CompositePrincipal(
        new ArnPrincipal(func.role.roleArn)
    )
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCBnYMCmAFKYAOwGNgwBDAGwBo4BBKIg4syquAXzgDMo04AcgoB3DAFoSAEwDW4qsABGAelETgFEIIDcAKFCRYiOADEArqRjAIRLr34ghaybPlLVY%20ZsVSKO3bpSOCRUFFA4cCQ2GPA8FiQAXKbxVjZ6%20jxwABRxpAB0-FQ4AJSIunAVkdHwFBgYZiA4UgBCAJ5wALxwRDgiKGiQWLgspOTUWeWVUz19jMyEo%20w58QUQRatFc8WTFducQA)

Comment: Thanks! This along with using role.grantAssumeRole() worked.

Comment: actually I was looking for role.addToPrincipalPolicy(new PolicyStatement({ policy allowing sts:AssumeRole })